# How to use iOS generated SDK for AWS API Gateway (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, aws-api-gateway

I've created a API using AWS API Gateway but whenever I try to access any resource, I receive this error.

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPBody=<CFBasicHash 0x7fd5d87baaf0 [0x102c007b0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
0 : message = <CFString 0x7fd5d87bf100 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "Not able to access resource."}
}
, HTTPHeaderFields=<CFBasicHash 0x7fd5d87bf2a0 [0x102c007b0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 8,
entries =>
0 : X-Cache = <CFString 0x7fd5d87bf030 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "Error from cloudfront"}
1 : Content-Type = <CFString 0x7fd5d87bd900 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "application/json"}
3 : x-amzn-RequestId = <CFString 0x7fd5d87baa70 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "2728fe5f-51b0-11e5-8d25-ada09d3fa091"}
4 : Via = <CFString 0x7fd5d87bcfb0 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "1.1 87b90692aeeb296771124f5335f08b68.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"}
6 : Date = <CFString 0x7fd5d87be8d0 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "Wed, 02 Sep 2015 20:21:11 GMT"}
10 : Content-Length = 43
11 : X-Amz-Cf-Id = <CFString 0x7fd5d87bd0f0 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "0aL_H-QzchVHBgsYChJ9YwJOs0PKpdFzouXJsDDausqQ9bpunaJmFg=="}
12 : Connection = <CFString 0x7fd5d87be8b0 [0x102c007b0]>{contents = "keep-alive"}
}
}
```

My resources require api key but no "Authorization type".

Here the snippet of my AppDelegate.swift where I configure my client:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    MYREKSMyreksApiClient.registerClientWithConfiguration(configuration, forKey: "avfhh3FNkh4JDGWG8AHsH4ogucFZjmkEUJIn0C44")
    return true
}
```

And this how I am calling from my Controller.

```
let serviceClient = CLIMyApiClient(forKey: apiKey)
    var object = CLICustomObject()
    object.param_01 = "Param 01"
    object.param_02 = "Param 02"
    let result = serviceClient.customObjectPost(contentShare).continueWithBlock{ (task:AWSTask!) -> (AnyObject!) in
        if task.error != nil {
            print(task.error)
        } else {
            print("Good!")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Any ideas why I getting that erro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've manage to identify the error...

There were a few mistakes in my code:

1. When I was registering my client "forKey", that key is only a Dict key to retrieve my client. I wasn't really adding my API Key there. So, I changed it to a more meaningful key.
2. To actually set my API Key in the client, I had to... well, Set it in the client:

   ```
   let serviceClient = CLIApiClient(forKey: "MoreMeaningfulKey")
   serviceClient.APIKey = "MyActuallyAPIKey"
   ```

That's it!

Apparently at AWS API Gateway, iOS and Android teams they don't talk to each other. That's how you call it on Android:

```
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory().endpoint(END_POINT).apiKey(API_KEY);
MyApiClient client = factory.build(MyApiClient.class);
```

Comment: I don't want to sound discouraging, but the generated SDK really disappointed me with their quality... Rolling custom and better isn't that big of a hassle.

Comment: hi, in iOS,  do you know how to change endpoint of CLIApiClient?

Comment: @User9527, in CLIApiClient.m file, you're gonna find the endpoint (generated). I guess you could just edit there.

Comment: @kixorz Can you share some code on how your rolled your own? I'm having a few issues trying the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293109/aws-api-gateway-creating-a-custom-client-for-swift-instead-of-using-the-gener

Comment: @Anil I don't have specific example, but I'd use AFNetworking with small wrapper around it. Depends on the features you're looking for... Like auth, which requires v4 signature routines etc.

Comment: @ademarizu can you please share your few code of android. I am trying since week but I can't understand how to pass api_key and how to pass my other parameter. I am too much confuse

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft, the snippet of code is in my answer, just bellow iOS code. Looks pretty straightforward to me, but maybe you could try explaining a bit more what is so confusing for you.